# How to achieve jQuery slideToggle functionality in Android

Tags: android, jquery-animate

I am looking for jQuery slideToggle like functionality in Android. Is there any way to achieve this. I searched for long time but did not found any thing. Please suggest me some source code snippet if it is possible. I want to achieve right Google Map button action in the URL: http://360.az/vt/avaz

Comment: Which version of Android is causing you trouble?

Comment: I am using version 3.0